# Python List indexing multiple ranges

Tags: python, list

Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find it anywhere.  Basically how do I get 2 separate ranges within a list in Python.

If I want the 1st, 2nd, 5th and 6th elements of a list I know I can do this,

```
l = range(0,15)
l[1:3]+l[5:7]
```

but this assumes that l is easy to write.  However I am scrapping something from a webpage using BeautifulSoup4, so I'm using soup.find_all (which gives me a list), so I can't simply write out 2 lists, l and concatenate them.

I want an answer that is something like

```
l = range(0,15)
l[1:3,5:7]
```

(but of course without the error) :)

Comment: what is wrong with `l[1:3]+l[5:7]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *might* be what you want.  `itemgetter` creates a function that retrieves the listed indices:

```
>>> import operator
>>> snip = operator.itemgetter(1,2,5,6)
>>> snip(range(15))
(1, 2, 5, 6)
>>> snip('abcdefg')
('b', 'c', 'f', 'g')
>>> snip([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
(2, 3, 6, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a function:

```
def multi_range(l, *args):
    output = []
    for indices in args:
        output += l[indices[0]:indices[1]]
    return output
```

So the first argument would be the list, and the rest of the parameters are tuples with the indices you're looking to pull. It would work fine with a long list name:

```
long_list_name = range(0, 15)
print multi_range(long_list_name, (1, 3), (5, 7))
>>> [1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = range(0, 15)
print([l[i] for i in [1,2, 5,6]])
```

Not sure why you think `l[1:3]+l[5:7]` is *hard*, find_all returns a normal python list like any other.

Or using map:

```
l = range(0, 15)
print(list(map(l.__getitem__,(1,2,5,6))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this OK?

```
indices = [1, 2, 5, 6]
selected = [l[i] for i in indices]
```